# Time stamping output files throws error for report

Tags: robotframework

```
call pybot --timestampoutputs --log mylog.html --report NONE tests.html      
  [ ERROR ] Parsing 'tests.html' failed: Data source does not exist.
```

I want to create report with time stamp but throws error. Any example as how to generate reports with unique name with time-date.

Answer (score 0):

The error you report, "`Data source does not exist`", is not because of your use of the `--timestampoutputs` option. It's because robot can't find "tests.html".

`--timestampoutputs` works fine when you give it a valid test suite. For example, when I ran the code in your question I ended up with a log file named `mylog-20150220-053904.html`.

Comment: Thank You. I dont know why it is not working for me but i am also using pybot --timestampoutputs --log mylog.html --report NONE tests.html  It generated log,report but not with timestamp. it still says failed: Data source does not exist and i don't know what it is.

Comment: Thank You very much for your help. Now i can create with time stamp.